# Text display quality in Visio 2010

Tags: fonts, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, cleartype

I'm missing text display quality settings (esp. *ClearType*) under Visio 2010. Any idea how to turn on *ClearType* rendering?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, and not configurable.  The registry key that fixed this on 2007 doesn't work on 2010 (I just tried it).

Comment: What OS are you using? I think that ClearType is an OS wide preference in Vista and 7.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10:

1. Open Settings in Start Menu, choose System and click Advanced display settings in Display.

   Tip: In Windows 10 Technical Preview computer, find Advanced display settings in PC settings/PC...
2. Tap ClearType text to continue.

Answer (score -1):

This is for the system, I don't know how well it will work for you, but it's worth a shot.

To enable and set up ClearType, follow these steps:

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Click on 'Appearance and Personalisation'
3. Click on 'Display'
4. Click on 'Adjust ClearType text'
5. Follow through the setup

it may also help to calibrate your display (this is completely optional)

1. Follow the first 3 steps of the ClearType setup
2. Click on 'Calibrate color'
3. Follow setup

You can also just do the calibrate display and the ClearType setup will also be at the end of it.

I hope this helped.